# How to center cells text for all tables within a document?

Tags: tables

I'm searching a simple way **to center by default** all cells content/text for all tables within my document.

Is there any simple way for that ?

Thank you in advance for help !

Comment: Depends on table type.  For example, using `tabular` specify column types as `c`. etc.

Comment: @Zarko  , i'm wanting to center the cells contents for all tables at the begining of my document. after \usepackage{}

Comment: Do you want to horizontally center or vertically center the contents? Please also include an example that shows how you currently create your tables.

Comment: how you imagine to write tables? specification always contains columns types. for it use `c`, if table use `tabular` table environment. BTW, your question is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In all tabulars (table is the floating object commonly put around a tabular) you have to give the number of columns. Thus is done by specifying the type of your column - e.g. \begin{tabular}{cc} for two centered columns.

If you want to rearrange your work, the clean thing is a regular expression search on your source code and replace them.